# Tracking App Installs using Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I have set up the facebook SDK according to the documentation on the Facebook developer website. I have also added the code below in applicationDidBecomeActive

```
-(void) applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication*)application 
{
 [FBSettings publishInstall:[FBSession defaultAppID]];
}
```

I have also set up the app in Facebook but it does not seem to be tracking the installs. I was wondering if anyone knew how long it takes for the installs to register. Does it even track installs when running from Xcode or an adHoc build? Or is there something that I may have missed. Any help would be much appreciated. 
Thanks